# how to develop Admin Panel in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an asp.net website in which i need to create admin panel.
 So please tell me how to decide role and membership and also way of development.

thanks

Comment: I want to develop admin panel for a website. for this i need some help that how can i decide which user is admin or guest and how to provide them membership......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will require some tools.

1. WebMatrix (or VS)
2. SQL Database.

Then by using these, the ASP.NET will automatically create the tables required using this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection();
```

You can learn about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection(v=vs.111).aspx

You will require to tell the name of Database and the Table name which will be used for the User Data. Remaining will be the job of ASP.NET like UserInRoles MemberShip and others

How to use those roles or others please go through this: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security

There you will learn:

1. How to allow users to Sign In or Sign Up.
2. How to add membership.
3. How to create Roles for users.

...and many more there. I will advise you to go to http://www.asp.net and learn the basics about it there. They are heplfull too. You will find many helpfull articles there. Find some community blogs too about ASP.NET.

**Edit:** They will teach you code regarding C# as well as VB.NET, but C# will be used more oftenly than VB.NET!

Comment: On an unrelated note, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871198/321973) is severely broken copy-pasta, which you should have flagged instead of [suggesting an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2952113) **edit** never mind, said post has been dealt with, but please flag such funky stuff in the future

Comment: What? O.o did I suggest an edit on a post with tag of `PHP`? I dont get it. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Lacking 10k neither of us can see that post which has been deleted, and so is the suggested edit... But basically you seem to have improved formatting there (a missing code indentation) - unless this was an audit gone rogue, since these tend to add real users to fake edit suggestions...

Comment: Well, I am having `PHP` as my tag that I hate. I have made these tags hidden. How are you supposed to say that I was editting it? Duh!

Comment: Very weird, so probably a bug and it wasn't you; unless you checked a review queue (first post, late answer, low quality) which I guess won't respect that

Comment: Well I skip any Question that has `PHP` tag. So I neither edit it, nor do I approve it. Unless it has no line of code!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on how to setup membership and roles in SQL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider

Answer (score 0):

This would be a start:

[Introduction to ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)